# SQL query to find all timestamps covered by an interval in A but not covered by an interval in B ("subtract" or "except" between multiple intervals)

Tags: sql, postgresql, intervals

I have multiple tables in a PostgreSQL 9.4 database, where each row contains an interval as two columns "start" (inclusive) and "stop" (exclusive).

Consider the following pseudo-code (the tables are more complicated).

```
CREATE TABLE left (   
    start TIMESTAMP,   
    stop TIMESTAMP,   
    [...] 
);

CREATE TABLE right (
    start TIMESTAMP,   
    stop TIMESTAMP,   
    [...] 
);
```

The intervals are inclusive of the start, but exclusive of the stop.

I now need a query to find all possible intervals of time where there is a row in "left" covering the interval, but not simultaneously a row in "right" covering the same interval.

One interval in "left" can be cut up into any number of intervals in the result, be shortened, or be entirely absent. Consider the following graph, with time progressing from left to right:

```
left     [-----row 1------------------)   [--row 2--)    [--row 3----)
right  [--row1--)    [--row2--)    [--row3--)         
result          [----)        [----)        [-------)    [-----------)
```

In this tiny example, "left" has tree rows each representing three intervals and "right" has three rows, each representing three other intervals.

The result has four rows of intervals, which together cover all possible timestamps where there is a row/interval in "left" covering that timestamp, but not a row/interval in "right" covering the same timestamp.

The tables are of course in reality very much larger than three rows each - in fact I will frequently be wanting to perform the algorithm between two subqueries that have the "start" and "stop" columns.

I have hit a dead end (multiple dead ends, in fact), and am on the virge of just fetching all records into memory and applying some procedural programming to the problem...

Any solutions or suggestions of what thinking to apply is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Look into timestamp range type `tsrange` [here's doc about ranges](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/rangetypes.html) There are some [useful operator for substraction, intersection etc](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-range.html). You could create `tsrange` from two values by calling ` tsrange(start_val, stop_val, '[)')`. Mayby this will help you.

Comment: Are the left intervals non-overlapping? (and similar for the right intervals)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the types of columns to `tsrange` (or create an appropriate views):

```
CREATE TABLE leftr (
    duration tsrange
);

CREATE TABLE rightr (
    duration tsrange
);

insert into leftr values
('[2015-01-03, 2015-01-20)'),
('[2015-01-25, 2015-02-01)'),
('[2015-02-08, 2015-02-15)');

insert into rightr values
('[2015-01-01, 2015-01-06)'),
('[2015-01-10, 2015-01-15)'),
('[2015-01-18, 2015-01-26)');
```

The query:

```
select duration* gap result
from (
    select tsrange(upper(duration), lower(lead(duration) over (order by duration))) gap
    from rightr
    ) inv
join leftr
on duration && gap

                    result                     
-----------------------------------------------
 ["2015-01-06 00:00:00","2015-01-10 00:00:00")
 ["2015-01-15 00:00:00","2015-01-18 00:00:00")
 ["2015-01-26 00:00:00","2015-02-01 00:00:00")
 ["2015-02-08 00:00:00","2015-02-15 00:00:00")
(4 rows)
```

The idea:

```
l          [-----row 1------------------)   [--row 2--)    [--row 3----)
r        [--row1--)    [--row2--)    [--row3--)
inv(r)            [----)        [----)        [------------------------->
l*inv(r)          [----)        [----)        [-------)    [-----------)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer! Although the SQL is at a high level, I think you explained clearly what's happening. I had looked at tsrange (but at the time didn't think it would help me very much), but I did not know about window functions. The combination of those two was pure dynamite, and I have an entire aspect of SQL to explore as a bonus! Big thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If the type change to `tsrange` is not an option, here an alternative solution using *window function*.

The important idea is to realize that *only the start and end points of the intervals are relavent*. In the first step a transformation in a sequence of starting and ending timestamps is performed. (I use numbers to simplify the example).

```
 insert into t_left 
 select 1,4 from dual union all
 select 6,9 from dual union all
 select 12,13 from dual    
 ;

 insert into t_right 
 select 2,3 from dual union all
 select 5,7 from dual union all
 select 8,10 from dual union all
 select 11,14 from dual    
 ;

 with event as  (
 select  i_start tst, 1 left_change, 0 right_change from t_left union all
 select  i_stop tst, -1 left_change, 0 right_change from t_left union all
 select  i_start  tst, 0 left_change, 1 right_change from t_right  union all
 select  i_stop tst, 0 left_change, -1 right_change from t_right
 )
 select tst, left_change, right_change,
 sum(left_change) over (order by tst) as is_left,
 sum(right_change) over (order by tst) as is_right,
 '['||tst||','||lead(tst) over (order by tst) ||')' intrvl
 from event
 order by tst;
```

This ends with a two recods for each interval one for start (+1) and one for end (-1 in the CHANGE column).

```
   TST LEFT_CHANGE RIGHT_CHANGE    IS_LEFT   IS_RIGHT INTRVL
```

---

```
     1           1            0          1          0 [1,2)     
     2           0            1          1          1 [2,3)     
     3           0           -1          1          0 [3,4)    
     4          -1            0          0          0 [4,5)    
     5           0            1          0          1 [5,6)    
     6           1            0          1          1 [6,7)      
     7           0           -1          1          0 [7,8)    
     8           0            1          1          1 [8,9)     
     9          -1            0          0          1 [9,10)     
    10           0           -1          0          0 [10,11)   
    11           0            1          0          1 [11,12)   
    12           1            0          1          1 [12,13)   
    13          -1            0          0          1 [13,14)   
    14           0           -1          0          0 [14,)
```

The window SUM finction

```
 sum(left_change) over (order by tst)
```

adds all changes so far, yielding the 1 for beeing **in interval** and 0 beeing **out of the interval**.

The filter to get all (sub)intervals that are *left only* ist therefore trivial

```
is_left = 1 and is_right = 0
```

The (sub)interval start with the timstamp of the current row and ends with the timstamp of the *next* row.

Final notes:

- You may need to add logik to ignore intervals of leghth 0
- I'm testing in Oracle, so pls re-check the Postgres functionality

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer! Your answer is complete and well explained - it has helped me greatly in understanding window functions. It is also an answer that I think many in my team will find helpful to them in understanding our final solution (which ever it will turn out to be).

Answer (score 0):

For completeness: the naive method, without using interval types.
[I used the same sample data as @klin ]

```
CREATE TABLE tleft (
    start TIMESTAMP,
    stop TIMESTAMP,
    payload text
);

INSERT INTO tleft(start,stop) VALUES
-- ('2015-01-08', '2015-03-07'),  ('2015-03-21', '2015-04-14'), ('2015-05-01', '2015-05-15') ;
('2015-01-03', '2015-01-20'), ('2015-01-25', '2015-02-01'), ('2015-02-08', '2015-02-15');

CREATE TABLE tright (
    start TIMESTAMP,
    stop TIMESTAMP,
    payload text
);
INSERT INTO tright(start,stop) VALUES
 -- ('2015-01-01', '2015-01-15'),  ('2015-02-01', '2015-02-14'), ('2015-03-01', '2015-04-07') ;
('2015-01-01', '2015-01-06'), ('2015-01-10', '2015-01-15'), ('2015-01-18', '2015-01-26');

        -- Combine all {start,stop} events into one time series
        -- , encoding the event-type into a state change.
        -- Note: this assumes non-overlapping intervals in both
        -- left and right tables.
WITH zzz AS (
    SELECT stamp, SUM(state) AS state
    FROM (
    SELECT 1 AS state, start AS stamp FROM tleft
        UNION ALL
        SELECT -1 AS state, stop AS stamp FROM tleft
    UNION ALL
        SELECT 2 AS state, start AS stamp FROM tright
        UNION ALL
        SELECT -2 AS state, stop AS stamp FROM tright
        ) zz
    GROUP BY stamp
    )
    -- Reconstruct *all* (sub)intervals
    -- , and calculate a "running sum" over the state variable
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT zzz.stamp AS zstart
        , LEAD(zzz.stamp) OVER (www) AS zstop
        , zzz.state
        , row_number() OVER(www) AS rn
        , SUM(state) OVER(www) AS sstate
FROM zzz
        WINDOW www AS (ORDER BY stamp)
        ) sub
        -- extract only the (starting) state we are interested in
WHERE sub.sstate = 1
ORDER BY sub.zstart
        ;
```

---

Result:

```
DROP SCHEMA
CREATE SCHEMA
SET
CREATE TABLE
INSERT 0 3
CREATE TABLE
INSERT 0 3
       zstart        |        zstop        | state | rn | sstate 
---------------------+---------------------+-------+----+--------
 2015-01-06 00:00:00 | 2015-01-10 00:00:00 |    -2 |  3 |      1
 2015-01-15 00:00:00 | 2015-01-18 00:00:00 |    -2 |  5 |      1
 2015-01-26 00:00:00 | 2015-02-01 00:00:00 |    -2 |  9 |      1
 2015-02-08 00:00:00 | 2015-02-15 00:00:00 |     1 | 11 |      1
(4 rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

If `tsrange` is not an option maybe stored procedure is?
Something like this:

```
--create tables
drop table if exists tdate1;
drop table if exists tdate2;

create table tdate1(start timestamp, stop timestamp);
create table tdate2(start timestamp, stop timestamp);

--populate tables
insert into tdate1(start, stop) values('2015-01-01 00:10', '2015-01-01 01:00');
insert into tdate2(start, stop) values('2015-01-01 00:00', '2015-01-01 00:20');
insert into tdate2(start, stop) values('2015-01-01 00:30', '2015-01-01 00:40');
insert into tdate2(start, stop) values('2015-01-01 00:50', '2015-01-01 01:20');
insert into tdate1(start, stop) values('2015-01-01 01:10', '2015-01-01 02:00');
insert into tdate1(start, stop) values('2015-01-01 02:10', '2015-01-01 03:00');

--stored procedure itself
create or replace function tdate_periods(out start timestamp, out stop timestamp)
    returns setof record as
$$
declare
    rec record;
    laststart timestamp = null;
    startdt timestamp = null;
    stopdt timestamp = null;
begin
    for rec in
        select
                t1.start as t1start,
                t1.stop as t1stop,
                t2.start as t2start,
                t2.stop as t2stop
            from tdate1 t1
            left join tdate2 t2 on t2.stop > t1.start or t2.start > t1.stop
    loop
        if laststart <> rec.t1start or laststart is null then
            if laststart is not null then
                if startdt < stopdt then
                    start = startdt;
                    stop = stopdt;
                    return next;

                    startdt = stopdt;
                end if;
            end if;

            startdt = rec.t1start;
            stopdt = rec.t1stop;

            laststart = startdt;
        end if;

        if rec.t2start is not null then
            if startdt < rec.t2start then
                start = startdt;
                stop = rec.t2start;
                return next;
            end if;

            startdt = rec.t2stop;
        end if;
    end loop;

    if startdt is not null and startdt < stopdt then
        start = startdt;
        stop = stopdt;
        return next;
    end if;
end
$$ language plpgsql;

--call
select * from tdate_periods();
```